# Selenium WebDriver: finding a button using button mode

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, find

I am trying to use Selenium Webdriver to find and click some buttons. 
The HTML code is:

```
<button class="btn param1 param2 param3 param4" na:mode="a.b.c" btn-checkbox="">First</button>
<button class="btn param1 param2 param3" na:mode="a.b.d" btn-checkbox="">Second</button>
<button class="btn param1 param2 param3" ng:mode="a.b.e" btn-checkbox="">Third</button>
```

I tried to use:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[na:mode="a.b.c"]')
```

But I get error that says `no such element: Unable to locate element`

What is the problem with the code I wrote? What is the best way to find these 3 buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS selector, . (dot) and :(colon) have different meanings. So It needs to be escaped with slash() as given below.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[na\:mode="a\.b\.c"]')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I get this error: `invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified`

Comment: sorry, i forget to escape colon(:) as well. updated the answer.

Comment: Great that worked, thank you so much, I upvoted and accepted your answer :)